# How can i call a Token based Action using Postman?

Tags: c#, postman

I have the following in my controller, DetailsController

```
    //GET: details/Login
    
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SignIn(string url)
    {            
        //code goes here            
    }

    [TokenAuthorization]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SiginUserTokenBased(string mytoken, string url)
    {
        //code goes here 
    }
```

From Postman i can call the signin actionresult by using https://localhost:55787/Details/signin?returnurl=??

How can i call the SiginUserTokenBased  , is it a get / post ?

Comment: Is it safe to assume your SignIn returns a token? if so u can add a token in postman under authorization.

Comment: Also there is no real indication if the endpoints are a Get or a Post. I would try to either add [httpsPost] inbefore a endpoint that is a post or add Post to the beginning of your method names. example GetSignIn() or PostSignUserTokenBased(). I can however assume both endpoints are a get as they have no body parameters.

Comment: Where is `[TokenAuthorization]` defined as filter attribute? I don't see its code

Comment: the functions both appear to be a get request, add `[HttpPost]` above your `SiginUserTokenBased` also what is authorization type for `[TokenAuthorization]`

Comment: the token is retrieved from a different app, if the token is valid I then call the SiginUserTokenBased Action.. but i cant seem to invoke that action ? I would have though it would have been as mentioned in the suggestions , Authorization Key ?
The controller is defined as:

     [Authorize]
    public class DetailsController : Controller

Answer (score 0):

Calling the **SignIn** function should return a **token**.

You can add the **token** to your **Postman** request from the **authorization** tab and choose **Bearer Token** from the **Type Dropdown** list.

[image]

Comment: I had the toekn in the request params . Should that not still work ? Like https://localhost:55787/Details/SiginUserTokenBased?token="mytokenvalue"

Comment: The token should be added in the request header not in the params

Answer (score 0):

In Your Postman: Choose the **Header** **Tab** to enter the **Authorization** in the **Key** Text Box and enter your token Prefix. Add "Bearer", one tab space and "Enter your token".

[image: Postman Image]

To Use **Get** Method

```
https://localhost:55787/Details/signin?returnurl=?? and also
```

Use `'[HttpGet]'` in Above of your Controller